# Database replication when the application is launched offline

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, pouchdb

I use PouchDB to store data offline and synchronize with a remote CouchDB database when the application goes online. It works well if the app is launched online: PouchDB triggers the `pause` event when the connexion is interrupted and continues when the connexion comes back. Here is a sample code:

```
localDB.replicate.to(remoteDB, {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('paused', function (info) {
  // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
}).on('change', function (change) {
  // yo, something changed!
}).on('active', function (info) {
  // replication was resumed
}).on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  // totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
})
```

But when the application is launched offline, an error is encountered (`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`)

the remote database can't be accessed and PouchDB triggers an `error` event (`"Database encountered an unknown error"`, status 500). Even if the connexion comes back, the replication will not work.

**Question:**
Is there a way to make the replication work even if the application is launched offline (for example by making the `pause` event comes first even if there is no access to the remote database yet)?

*UPDATE:*
Thanks to nlawson for the answer! I just had to add the remote database creation in the function to make it work:

```
function retryReplication() {
  var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://129.199.80.62:5984/remotedb');
  localDB.replicate.to(remoteDB, {
  live: true,
  }).on('paused', function (info) {
    // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
  }).on('change', function (change) {
    // yo, something changed!
  }).on('active', function (info) {
    // replication was resumed
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    setTimeout(retryReplication, 5000);
    // totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
  });
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should probably be a bug report on Github rather than a question on StackOverflow. :) I [filed it here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3768).

The `retry` replication should definitely work regardless of whether it starts in offline or online mode. I'm sorry you ran into this bug!

In the meantime, you can avoid the `retry` option and do the retry replication yourself. You can find [a description of how to do that here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/263fd7fdb9fd7f4c0b8026bcdf95b19b677e552a/docs/_guides/replication.md#live-replication).

**Update:** this bug was fixed in PouchDB 3.6.0.